# TableLayoutPanel sizing doesn't work (C#)

Tags: c#, size, cells, tablelayoutpanel

I have the following code in my Windows Forms application:

```
x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = x;
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = x;
```

I have a textbox which determines the number of the rows and columns of a table layout panel. The problem is, that the cells look like this:

[the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6wzZ.png)

What can I do to make the size of the cells the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `RowStyles` and `ColumnStyles` properties?

```
TableLayoutRowStyleCollection styles =
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles;

foreach (RowStyle style in styles){
   // Set the row height to 20 pixels.
   style.SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
   style.Height = 20;
}
```

and also:

```
TableLayoutColumnStyleCollection styles =
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles;

foreach (ColumnStyle style in styles){
   // Set the column width to 20 pixels.
   style.SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
   style.Width = 20;
}
```

You can just use `RowStyles` if you want by adding the `width` of the row.